# Load Balancing "Hello World" Kubernetes application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

To start playing with Kubernetes I created a small project where I create a three nodes cluster on my local machine using Vagrant and Vbox:
https://github.com/sasadangelo/k8s-cluster

Just typing `vagrant up` my cluster is up and running and I can start to play with it. I got familiar with the main concepts and commands and created a simple "Hello World" application composed by a docker image with an NGINX web server where you can connect via browser and a "Hello World" message appears with the hostname. The hostname helps me to understand which Pod responded to my request.

Here the project:
https://github.com/sasadangelo/k8s-tutorials/tree/master/hello-k8s

Currently, I can create a deployment with `kubectl create` exposing it as a service with `kubectl expose` and then increase replica with `kubect scale`. At the moment, I am able to use use NodePort service, so with `kubectl describe service` I can see on which IP the 5 Pods listen, I connect to them and everything works fine.

My problem is that now I want to load balance the traffic. **I want to connect to a single IP** and as soon as I click on the browser Reload button I want to see that different Pod names appear.

I know that Kubernetes by default offers only NodePort service and if I want a load balancer I need something like an Ingress. I also know that a simple reverse proxy like Ingress Nginx is a good implementation for my needs.

However, I read lot of tutorials but I have hard time understanding how I should configure it to achieve what I need.

Here code I have so far:
https://github.com/sasadangelo/k8s-cluster/tree/master/ingress

Can anyone help me how to fix Ingress code to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kube Proxy which is a kubernetes component provides load balancing at L4 layer via iptables load balancing.So with ClusterIP type service itself you get load balancing between pods. But with clusterIP type service you can not access it from outside the cluster i.e from a browser. Nodeport type service provides access to the pods from outside the cluster with load balancing at L4 layer by kube proxy.

LoadBalancer and Ingress provides load balancing and rule based routing at L7 layer if that's what you are looking for.

Looking at your code you have yamls for nginx ingress controller and exposed it as Nodeport. What you need next is to create an ingress resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 8080
```

Once you create above ingress and you have a ClusterIP type service for your pod with a name web which exposed port 8080, You should be able to access it.

Here is the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) on using nginx ingress for an hello world application on Minikube which you can follow to make ingress work in your setup as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, you're right. After my post, I looked at this video and I realized https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VicH6KojwCI that I accessed the Pod via 172.16.x.x address directly to the endpoint and NodePort already provide load balancing using one of the two public node IP 192.168.x.x. You mentioned L4 and L7 where I can find documentation about this layers?

Comment: Another question. You said: "Nodeport type service provides access to the pods from outside the cluster with load balancing at L4 layer by kube proxy." As said in my previous comment I noticed that accessing to my two public IP nodes 192.168.x.x I got what I needed. My surprise is that I have to select the IP of one of the two nodes but there is no a single IP. Is this normal?

Comment: I added the code in the nginx-ingress-svc.yaml and called "kubectl apply -f nginx-ingress-svc.yaml". The ingress resource was successfully created but it's not clear to me how to determine the hostname or IP to put in the browser. I tried hello-world.info:8080 but it didn't work. Can you clarify?

Comment: yeah its normal..a nodeport within the range 30000-32767)will be listening in all of your nodes..so you can access the service using any of your node IP.

Comment: When you use ingress you access it via the nodeport of the ingress controller...you must have a nodeport service for ingress controller...use that nodeport

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you help me with my latest comment before your latest comment?

Comment: You can access it via IP:PORT where IP is ip of the node where ingress ingress controller pod is deployed and port is nodeport of the service for nginx ingress controller

Comment: I needed to adapt the code you posted above to my need. If I well understand, "serviceName: hello-k8s" and "servicePort: 80". Since I am already able to do load balancing with only a NodePort, ingress is only required to use a lower port (like 80) for my service so users should not specify it (this is what I understand from video I linked above). I applied the change. Now ingress-controller is deployed on k8s-node-1 with IP 192.168.1.11 and port is 80, but when I put it in the browser nothing happen. What am I missing?

Comment: Uploaded here my code, hope you can help me to figure out what is wrong. https://github.com/sasadangelo/k8s-cluster/tree/master/ingress

Comment: For your info, I solved my issue and documented in detail how I solved it. The only bad thing is that I needed to add a routing rule and I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done in detail to solve the issue. First of all, I installed Nginx Ingress resources:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml
```

then I create an Nginx Ingress resource in a `ingress-nginx.yaml` file:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-k8s-ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-k8s.info
      http:
      paths:
    - path: /
      backend:
        serviceName: hello-k8s
        servicePort: 80
```

and installed it with the command:

```
kubectl apply -f ingress-nginx.yaml
```

You can see [code here](https://github.com/sasadangelo/k8s-cluster/tree/master/ingress).

Inside the cluster (doing vagrant ssh on whatever node) I tested:

```
curl -H "Host: hello-k8s.info" IP
```

where IP is got from the command:

```
kubectl get ingress
```

Suppose it is `10.97.139.101`. Outside the cluster, on my Mac (Running on 3 VirtualBox on my Mac) to access the application I needed to add a route:

```
sudo route add -net 10.97.0.0/16 192.168.205.10
```

where 192.168.205.10 is the IP of the master node. In `/etc/hosts` I added the line:

```
10.97.139.101 hello-k8s.info
```

Now typing hello-k8s.info in the browser I see the "Hello World" web page appear.
Thanks to Arghya Sadhu for help.

Comment: Added tutorial here https://github.com/sasadangelo/k8s-tutorials/tree/master/hello-k8s-ingress